# Error: Unresolved external symbol error in C++

Tags: c++, unresolved-external

The compilation issue is caused by the global variable [ `All_Sockets` ], here is the minimal example

main.cpp

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include "global.h"


int main() {

    std::vector<SOCKET> All_Sockets(10, INVALID_SOCKET);    // definition of global var

    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

global.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

extern std::vector<SOCKET> All_Sockets;      // declaration of global variable
```

file1.cpp

```
#include "global.h"
#include <windows.h>

void ftn1(){
    int i = 2;
    SOCKET Client_socket = All_Sockets[i];      // usage of global var
}
```

I'm building this project in visual studio and the following linking error occurs

```
1>file1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::vector<unsigned int,class std::allocator<unsigned int> > All_Sockets"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define `All_Sockets` as global variable. Currently, `All_Sockets` is defined as local variable, so `All_Sockets` must be defined above `main` function.

```
std::vector<SOCKET> All_Sockets(10, INVALID_SOCKET);    // definition of global var

int main() {
    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought only the declaration should be global. thanks for the reply :)